# Openshift Online 503 Service Unavailable -- site was working fine for days now has error

Tags: openshift, http-status-code-503

I have tried restart from web console.  I have connected via ssh and run ctl_app restart.  Site is scaled.    PHP 5 site with MySQL 5.5 cartridge.  I haven't made any changes in weeks.

Comment: Is there anything useful in the error logs?

Comment: Try viewing your app-domain.rhcloud.com/haproxy-status page and see what it says, also, anything in the logs as someone commented above?